# Attempting to give html audio player specific customization of component visibiltiy and component colors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I am attempting to customize the html audio player by removing the volume icon, volume slider, and progress slider, adding the "/" and the total time of the audio track to the right of the current time of the audio track, and changing the color of the progress bar that has already been played to blue.

Since, my customization requirements appear to be unique, is there anyone who can help me with this? Much appreciated and thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot style the default player.  You must create your own with HTML/CSS and use JavaScript to control the audio.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video